# Prime numbers of the form $p^{x}+C$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let it be $\mathbb{P}$ the set of prime numbers. Let it be $p\in\mathbb{P}$ some prime number, and $C$ some fixed constant such that $p+C\in\mathbb{P}$. One might wonder if there exist infinitely many $x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p^{x}+C\in\mathbb{P}$.

For instance, taking $p=2$, and noticing that $2+1\in\mathbb{P}$, it might be wondered if there exist infinitely many $x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2^{x}+1\in\mathbb{P}$. Until today, this particular case remains unanswered, because if is known that  $2^{x}+1\in\mathbb{P}$ only if $x$ is of the form $x=2^n$, but it is not known if there exist infinite values of $x$ of the form $x=2^n$ such that $2^{x}+1\in\mathbb{P}$ (that is, it is not know if there exist infinitely many Fermat primes).

I am interested in known general results regarding this problem (if any).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: p,C have to be opposite parity.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee that is a given fact of the problem, as $p+C\in\mathbb{P}$ only if $\gcd(p,C)=1$, and $\gcd(p^x,C)=\gcd(p,C)$

Comment: $\gcd(p^x,C)\mid \gcd(p,C)^x$ to be more general

Comment: We won't be able for any pair $a,b$ of positive integers to prove that $a^x+b$ with positive integer $x$ produces infinite many prime numbers. Neither can we usually disprove it, unless there is a cover system showing that all but possibly finite many such numbers must be composite , or we can find algebraic or aurifeuillan factors.

Comment: In fact , it is even unknown whether infinite many Fermat primes exist , although the chance for such a prime larger than $2^{16}+1$ is less than $1:10^9$